# Should I inherit from both nn.Module and ABC?

Tags: python, pytorch, abstract-class

Should I create a class that inherits both from `torch.nn.Module` and `ABC`? And is it acceptable to call the `__init__()` function of `ABC`? (I guess it's ok since the `ABC` class is just a trivial subclass of `object`)

If I should use the `NotImplemented` way, how can I decide when to use which way?

I use the `AbstractModel` to initialize the config for all the children modules.

```py
import torch.nn as nn
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractModel(nn.Module, ABC):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
    
    @abstractmethod
    def generate(self):
        pass
    
class sub(AbstractMode):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)

    def generate(self):
        print(self.config)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to [@Nopileos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099815/10886420) you should use the `NotImplementedError` as well as `abc`, as it does not allow inheriting class to call `super()` and use these methods.

One example could be:

```
import abc

import torch


class Base(torch.nn.Module, abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, out_features: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.module = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.LazyLinear(out_features * 2),
            torch.nn.GELU(),
            torch.nn.LazyLinear(out_features),
        )

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ResnetLike(Base):
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        # super().forward(x) would raise an error correctly
        return self.module(x) + x


class TestNetwork(Base):
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        return self.module(x) * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `ABC` in some base module which also inherits from `nn.Module` and so far I did not encounter any problems with it. They is no clash in what both provide ad as you said `ABC` is a fairly simple class

You should favor it instead of doing `NotImplemented`.

[ABC also states](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f709bdb86261fdba3ea8e5fd529f8af9fca4f42/Lib/abc.py#L92)

> Metaclass for defining Abstract Base Classes (ABCs). Use this metaclass to create an ABC. An ABC can be subclassed directly, and then acts as a mix-in class.

So it acts as a [mixin](https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2020/03/27/mixin-classes-in-python/#mixin-classes) class, which means it is small, lightweight and basically adds a specific feature to the class and should not have conflicts with any other classes you inherit from.